# where does "Generate Flow Chart..." Come from under Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008

When I right-click the source code of aspx.cs code under Visual Studio 2008, I noticed there is an option called "Generate Flow Chart...".  It generates pretty good flow chart under a method. I just wonder where it comes from. is it a built-in or from other add-ins.
I have several add-ins and just confused.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft Visual Studio Learning Pack 2.0

The Visual Studio Learning Pack 2.0 is a software package created by Microsoft to help students learn about computer programming.

More details at:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=0ce3cbbd-7fc7-410b-8c2c-e18d1c60a6cd

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is very useful for programmers of all levels.